# Can't get instagram newly added business account through API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I am facing issue for Instagram business accounts retrieving from API.

Client is already authorized my app and after some time they converted there Instagram personal account to business account.

When i try to fetch newly added Instagram business account they are not showing in API response.

Every time i have to remove app from account and re-authorized. I re-authenticated app still not get newly added business account.

Guys any solution for this ??

Here is a screenshot for more info http://nimb.ws/zfwl7e

```
 function fb_reauthenticate_relink()
 {

    $helper = $this->fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
    $permissions = ['email', 'public_profile', 'manage_pages', 'read_insights', 'publish_pages', 'instagram_basic', 'instagram_manage_comments', 'instagram_manage_insights'];
    $loginUrl = $helper->getReAuthenticationUrl('facebook_reauthenticate_callback', $permissions);
    redirect($loginUrl);
 }

function facebook_reauthenticate_callback()
{
    $helper = $this->fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

    try
    {
        $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
    } catch (Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e)
    {
        // When Graph returns an error
        echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    } catch (Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e)
    {
        // When validation fails or other local issues
        echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }


    $raw_accessToken = (string) $accessToken;

    $oAuth2Client = $this->fb->getOAuth2Client();

    $longLivedAccessToken = (string) $oAuth2Client->getLongLivedAccessToken($raw_accessToken);


    $url = "https://graph.facebook.com/v3.1/me/accounts?fields=instagram_business_account,connected_instagram_account,global_brand_page_name,access_token&access_token=" . $longLivedAccessToken;
    $request_response = $this->curl_request($url);

    // In $request_response didn't get newly added business profile

}
```

Comment: You should include your code related to the issue.

Comment: Here is a screenshot for more info http://nimb.ws/zfwl7e

Comment: *You should include your code related to the issue.*

Comment: In my post i added code.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/238190646876693/?disable_redirect=0